# Xpath with xmlns and it doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xquery

I got something like this.

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = CONVERT (XML, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
            <Response xmlns="http://domain1.net/">
                  <Result>Success</Result>
                        <info>
                              <task>
                                    <Dt>01/7/2011</Dt>
                                    <ref>
                                          <RefNo>123456789</RefNo>
                                    </ref>
                              </task>
                        </info>
            </Response>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
')
```

How do I get the value of RefNo?

I tried these but it's not working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS O_CaseID
    , GETDATE() Create_Dt
FROM @XML.nodes('//RefNo') t(c)

SELECT DISTINCT
    c.value('(//RefNo.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS O_CaseID
    , GETDATE() Create_Dt
FROM @XML.nodes('//.') t(c)
```

Any idea? Do i need to use local-name()? but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have XML namespaces in your XML document - and you need to **use those** - not just ignore them!

Try this query:

```
-- define the two relevant XML namespaces for your query
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS soap, 
                   'http://domain1.net/' AS ns)
SELECT 
    c.value('(ns:RefNo)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS O_CaseID
FROM 
    -- USE those namespaces as needed!
    @XML.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns:Response/ns:info/ns:task/ns:ref') t(c)
```

Comment: Tks it works. I simplified it as below and I was able to get the value I wanted.

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://domain1.net/' AS ns)
 SELECT 
  c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS O_CaseID
 FROM
    @XML.nodes('//ns:RefNo') t(c)

Comment: @Trowa: depending on the size of your XML, using `//....` is **not** recommended for performance reasons. Also: this selects **all** instances of `<RefNo>` anywhere in your XML document - which might or might not be what you want

Comment: Yes, I understand that. for my scenario there shouldn't be a large XML to be parsed. tks again for your help and pointed out the things to take into consideration.